# Jakarta mapping create Global Temporary Table and don't save inherited fields

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm updating and old project from java 7, hibernate 4.1  to springboot 3.1 java 17, hibernate 6.2  and jakarta 3.1.
I have a simple entity with inherited fields like following :

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class GenericEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

the child class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CommonAttributes extends GenericEntity {

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String userName;
}
```

and

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@Table(name = "WORKER")
public class Worker extends CommonAttributes {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 781441006067060800L;


    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

}
```

When I run my application I find on DB the table HTE_WORKER and when I call my controller to salve a Worker the field "username" is not saved.

My application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:xxxx:DBNAME
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=myuser

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

logging.level.root=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.security = trace
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

Here my controller, service and repository

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private WorkerService workerService;

    @PostMapping(path= "/user")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addEmployee(@RequestBody Worker worker){
        Worker worker1 = workerService.saveWorker(worker);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
    }

}
```

```
@Service("workerService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements WorkerService {

    @Autowired
    private LoginRepository loginRepository;

    @Override
    public Worker saveWorker(Worker worker) {
        return loginRepository.save(worker);
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface LoginRepository extends CrudRepository<Worker, Long> {

    Optional<Worker> findByUserName(String userName);


}
```

I used
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "hibernate_sequence_generator") @SequenceGenerator(name = "hibernate_sequence_generator", sequenceName = "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)`

HLE table is not created and the field "username" is not saved yet

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It might be a good idea to first upgrade to Java 8, then to the latest 2.x Spring Boot version (and corresponding hibernate versions etc.), then to Java 17 and then to Spring Boot 3.x.

Comment: To avoid the creation of global temporary table using hibernate 6 we need to chage @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) to @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) and than add to application.properties spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy=legacy